# symbolic links broken after installing mavericks

Tags: shell, symlink

I just updated to Mavericks and it has broken my sym links to Sublime Text, which I used to open by running the `sub` command. Therefore, I tried to create a new symlink by doing this

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /bin/sub
```

When I run the command `sub`, it says the command isn't found.

When I tried to create the symlink again by doing

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /bin/sub
```

it said

```
ln: /bin/sub: File exists
```

Any idea what I've done wrong or how I can get it to work?

Comment: For the `File exists`, simply remove `/bin/sub`. To get the link to actually work, don't mix quotes and escaped spaces; `sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /bin/sub` should be sufficient.

Comment: @admdrew I did `rm /bin/sub` and, once it was finished  ` sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime \Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /bin/sub` and I got this response `ln: /bin/sub: No such file or directory`  Did my `rm /bin/sub` remove something it shouldn't have?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, I was both enclosing the path in quotes and inserting a backslash before the space. Doing so links to a non-existant file at a path which actually has a real backslash character in its name. The symlink exists, but its target doesn't. Instead, I should have beeen creating the symlink like so:

```
sudo rm /bin/sub;
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /bin/sub
```

However, it's best to not make modifications to the /bin directory. Instead, it's safer to use the /usr/local hierarchy like so:

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/sub
```

Thanks to 5HT-2a